# Missing value from dropdown menus in php

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm trying to implement a double dropdown menu table on PHP.
I would like the user to choose two languages and then submit them to perform some queries.
Unfortunately, only one of the two values selected is selected, does anyone know why?
I'll leave the code here:

```
            echo '<div class="row">';
                    echo '<form style="text-align:center" method="post" action="">';
                        echo '<div class="column">';
                            echo '<p>
                                <h3>Original language?<h3><br>
                                <select name="formLanguageStart">
                                  <option value="">Select one</option>
                                  <option value="it">Italian</option>
                                  <option value="en">English</option>
                                  <option value="zh">Chinese</option>
                                </select>
                            </p>';
                        echo '</div>';
                        echo '<div class="column">'; 
                            echo '<p>
                                <h3>Destination language?<h3><br>
                                <select name="formLanguagDest">
                                  <option value="">Select one</option>
                                  <option value="it">Italian</option>
                                  <option value="en">English</option>
                                  <option value="zh">Chinese</option>
                                </select>
                            </p>';
                        echo '</div>';
                    echo ' <input type="submit" value="Load translation table"/></form>';
                echo '</div>';
```

The form gets visualized correctly, but printing the two $_POST[] values it can be noted that one is missing

Comment: why are you using `echo` inconsistently for displaying the form rather then just putting it in an HTML file?

Comment: you need JS for this and you didn't post what's happening *after* all this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're having trouble getting the `formLanguageDest` value, it may be because of a typo in your second `select` tag.

You wrote:

```
...
<select name="formLanguagDest">
...
```

I guess you meant `formLanguageDest`, right? Double check your $_POST statements and names.

Comment: I literally just lost one hour of my life trying to fix this. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Just tested your code, everything works as it should. Could you please tell me, how exactly do you print $_POST values?

EDIT: I used  `print_r($_POST);` to test this.

EDIT: You have "formLanguagDest" defined incorrectly. Shouldn't it be "**formLanguageDest**"?